# How can I fetch data from MySQL in jQuery without a click of a button using an hidden field value?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I'm trying to fetch a user information from MySQL by passing the value of an hidden field to jQuery without needing to click on a button, just at an interval of every x-minutes.

What I have so far:

```
function getdetails() {
    var value = $('#userId').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getInfo.php",
        data: 'myinfo=' + value,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#info").val(data);
        }
    });
    setInterval(function () {
        getdetails()
    }, 1000);
};
```

**getinfo.php**

```
  $id = $_POST['myinfo'];
  $query = "select * from alumni_users where userId = '$id' ";
  $update = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($update)){
  .......
  }
```

Comment: Three things.  #1) Do not create an interval **inside** the getdetails().  Each time you call it, you'll start up another interval. === bad time.  #2) Your mysql is not using prepared statements so it can be vulnerable to sql injection attacks.  #3) Your mysql is searching for a user by their id...... so why the `while` loop?  There should just be (at most) one result.

Comment: #4) Show us what logic is geing done to return the results to the ajax in the `.......` php part

Comment: Agree with what has been said.  Frankly, your code looks fine, I would just put the interval outside of the function call.

Comment: @Christiano Soares, Thanks for your reply and suggestions. Replying to #3), it actually fetches all the details concerning that particular user in the table. So, there could be multiple info assigned to his/her userID which means my loop is right. Furthermore, on the logic, an echo will return the data from the php part.

Comment: Do you have any **specific** question about this code? Anything not working as expected? Also, be warned that your query is highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

your php script:

```
if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
        $action = $_POST["action"];
        switch ($action) {
            case 'SLC':
                if (isset($_POST["id"])) {
                    $id = $_POST["id"];
                    $query = "select * from alumni_users where userId=?";
                    $update = mysqli_execute_query($mysqli, $query, [$id]);
                    $response = array();
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($update)){
                        .......
                        fill your response here
                    }
                    echo json_encode($response);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Where action is a command you want to do SLC, UPD, DEL etc and id is a parameter

then in your ajax:

```
function getdetails() {
    var value = $('#userId').val();
   return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "getInfo.php",
        data: 'myinfo=' + value
    })

}


call it like this:

getdetails().done(function(response){
var data=JSON.parse(response);
if (data != null) {
//fill your forms using your data
}
})
```